# How to Enable SSI (Server Side Includes) on Tomcat 7 at Ubuntu?

Tags: html, tomcat, ubuntu, include, ssi

How can I enable SSI on Tomcat 7?.

I follow the directions however it doesn't work. I changed my main file's extension from html to shtml (not imported one) and unquoted that lines at web.xml:

```
<servlet>

    <servlet-name>ssi</servlet-name>

    <servlet-class>

      org.apache.catalina.ssi.SSIServlet

    </servlet-class>

    <init-param>

      <param-name>buffered</param-name>

      <param-value>1</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <init-param>

      <param-name>debug</param-name>

      <param-value>0</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <init-param>

      <param-name>expires</param-name>

      <param-value>666</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <init-param>

      <param-name>isVirtualWebappRelative</param-name>

      <param-value>0</param-value>

    </init-param>

    <load-on-startup>4</load-on-startup>

</servlet>
```

What do do more, where is the wrong?

Comment: Have you added the SSL config to the Tomcat configuration file?

Comment: @Chris Can you explain what you mean?

Answer (score 3):

You also need to uncomment the SSI servlet mapping in web.xml

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ssi</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.shtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And create $CATALINA_HOME/conf/Catalina/localhost/<your app name>.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context privileged="true" >
</Context>
```

Answer (score -1):

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Introduction_to_SSL

You have to add the SSL configuration to the tomcat config this is detailed above and should help you out any questions after reading this let me know

Comment: I think there is a misunderstood here. I added an explanation to title of question.

Comment: The question is about SSI, not SSL.